# Inject variable into single quote string

Tags: ruby

I have the following string:

```
'-variable #{ENV['TEXT']}',
```

When I'm trying to inject `#{ENV['TEXT']}`, `ENV['TEXT']` isn't seen as a variable.

I tried using the double quote but with the double-quote it doesn't work.

Comment: Single quotes do not interpolate. Use `"`.

Comment: How does double quotes not work? Can you show us some output from IRB or something? That way we can see how it parses the strings

Comment: First of all, if you need to interpolate you should use `"-variable #{ENV['TEXT']}"`. Second, why is there a comma at the end of your example?

Comment: From http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html: `Double-quote strings allow interpolation of other values using #{...} ... . ... Interpolation may be disabled by escaping the “#” character or using single-quote strings`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use double-quotes or `%Q(...)` to interpolate variables into a string:

```
foo = 'word'
'a #{foo}' # => "a \#{foo}"
"a #{foo}" # => "a word"
%Q(a #{foo}) # => "a word"
```

There are other ways but that's a different question.